# Third monitor slow refresh when using USB to HDMI adapter

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, refresh-rate

I am using a Display Link USB to HDMI adapter to connect the third monitor to my laptop.

The monitor has an extremely slow refresh. If I move a chrome window to that monitor, it takes at least 10 seconds for a window refresh to happen.

Is there any way this could be resolved. I tried other USB ports, changing the refresh rate and restarting the system

Comment: Part of the reason that it is slow is that you are not using an `USB to HDMI adapter`. You are using a USB based graphical card. (and adapter would just convert stuff, or rewire connections. The actual card in that little DisplayLink  device contains an actual graphics card.). Since your card is fed its data from USB and USB is relative slow (compared to PCI and PCIe) it will always be slower than the output of your normal card. 
Having written all that:  One refresh per 1/4 th second would not be strange, but one per 10 seconds is not normal. Something is going wrong.

Comment: Yet there is not enough information in the post to help you. Can you try the stick on another computer and verify that it works fine on that? Can you tell us which model and if you connect it to an USB 1, and USB 2 or an USB3 port? Does the fresh rate get better is you use a lower resolution (which would indicate that is is not getting its data fast enough). Etc etc.