# I'm getting lag to external monitor (slow refresh rate) when using USB 3.0 to HDMI adapter

Tags: usb, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, external-display

When I use laptop HDMI port, my external monitor works fine but when I use USB 3.0 type A to HDMI (adapter) then then external monitor is so laggy an works very very slow.

Not all USB-C 3.0 has DisplayPort support, my laptop is one of them. My external monitor which is connected through HDMI port is working fine, problem is only with USB 3.0 type A port.

Specifications :

1. OS: Win 10 Pro 64bit
2. CPU: Intel i7
3. Graphics Card:
   [image: GeForce MX150]
4. Adapter (Amazon Link): [USB to HDMI Adapter, HD 1080P USB 3.0/2.0](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B0CQP2HKH8)
5. USB drivers I have tried V2.0.1 but it didn't help: [MSDisplay_MultiDev_v1.0.0.18.0.exe](https://github.com/MindShow/USBDisplay/blob/main/README.md)
6. Solutions I tried (YouTube videos): [How to Fix a Laggy Desktop on an External Monitor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bKemL534Jcg) and
   [External Monitor Boosts Laptop Gaming Performance!?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U1-S0VL5Duk)

Any solution for this problem? Because I want to use two independent monitors at same time.

Comment: Are you saying that the monitor connected THROUGH The USB-HDMI adapter is lagging, or that when you have this adapter connected to your computer, a monitor NOT connected through it is lagging? Please clarify this arrangement in your question by using the EDIT button.

Comment: If your laptop already has a working HDMI port, what are you trying to accomplish using this adapter? Is it the same computer, or a different one? What does "laggy" mean in this context?

Comment: Because I want to use two monitors with my laptop.

Comment: Because I want to use two monitors with my laptop. Laggy means very bad refresh rate. Slow response time. When you try to play YouTube video when browser tab is open on monitor connected with ADAPTER then video buffers a lot and so much lag.

Comment: If your laptop has any USB-C ports, try a USB-C to HDMI "alt mode" adapter. They're a much cleaner more reliable solution.

Comment: Please note that I asked you to EDIT your question to add that information. It is in your best interest that your question is clearer and more complete than it currently is, and adding this clarifying information will help do that.

Comment: Not all USB-C 3.0 has DisplayPort support, my laptop is one of them. My external monitor which is connected through HDMI port is working fine, problem is only with USB 3.0 type A port. Adapter link and driver info is provided in question. Let me know what specific details you want me to share.

Answer (score 0):

Same question from a while back. No answers, but the comment gives the answer: [Third monitor slow refresh when using USB to HDMI adapter](https://superuser.com/questions/572097/third-monitor-slow-refresh-when-using-usb-to-hdmi-adapter)

You are not adding screens to your internal GPU; your non-DP USB3 port requires the adapter to actually be a USB-connected GPU, and that will be slow. The root issue is that you are trying to push a LOT of data over the USB link, and even at the very good USB3 speeds, the internal data lanes between the system and the integrated GPU are orders of magnitude faster. With your current hardware you will have to accept a certain amount of delay on the screen connected via this USB-HDMI adapter.

**Things you can try**

- Update the drivers, or just try different drivers. This only has a small chance of being possible or helping, but it's easy to try and so can be tried.
- Try a different adapter, such as the alt-mode adapter Spiff recommended in their comment.

Comment: Sure. I'll try above solutions.